# Books on integrals, differential equations, limits or series/sequences [solved problems]?

Tags: calculus, reference-request, book-recommendation

I recently passed a course in calculus and i'm afraid i'm starting to forget things. While I do have the theory, I lack examples to practice in order to avoid losing my "momentum".

So, if you know any book with solved exercises (the more the better) in integrals, differential equations and so on, let me know!

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Solve  your course textbook problems. Anyway try this :

> [Schaum's $3,000$ Solved Problems in Calculus: Elliott Mendelson](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0071635343)

Answer (score 1):

Demidovich-Problems in mathematical analysis might be what you're looking for.

You can easily find a pdf online.